# Tryna Make a 3D Platformer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling, compiler-errors

This's really bugging me, because I've been looking all over for a solution.
Excuse my terrible code :/

Error:

> RespawnController.cs(13,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Code:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RespawnController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float ResPoint = -16.0f;
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GameObject.Find("PlayerCapsule").transform.position;
        if (transform.position.y == ResPoint)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `GameObject.Find("PlayerCapsule").transform.position;` to do?

Comment: I expect it to find the position of the player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what would happen if I write a statement in C# like:

```
10;
```

Your first reaction to this would probably be "Yeah? 10... what?" It's not clear what is intended by this statement.

That's basically what the following line does:

```
GameObject.Find("PlayerCapsule").transform.position;
```

This is a value. You need to do some kind of operation on it.

The next line won't compile either because you don't have any variable named `transform`.

I assume that you meant to store the result of `GameObject.Find` in a variable and then refer to it in the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I exactly turn this into an operation? I just assumed that since it was in the update loop that it would automatically start getting the position every frame.

Comment: It will compile, transform is the transform of game object that this script is atached to. Good answer though.
@theanythinggamerYT you need to assign your vector to the position you found. GameObject.Find("PlayerCapsule").transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
transform.position refers to the position of the gameObject this script is atached to, which is your respawner.

Comment: I'm actually going to attach this script to the player, because the function of it is to teleport the player to 0,0,0 when it's yPos is below -16. Do you know what do do for that?